# Twitter activity account api returns 403

Tags: node.js, twitter, postman

I tested this api - https://api.twitter.com/1.1/account_activity/all/develop/webhooks.json on postman and I appended my webhook url as a query parameter but I have been getting 403 Forbidden error, even though all my Oauth credentials are correct.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Can't register webhook for Twitter Account Activity API \[python3\]](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51225823/cant-register-webhook-for-twitter-account-activity-api-python3)

Comment: No. It doesn't.